# Call function on timer

Tags: jquery

I have a function that advances a slideshow image when a user clicks a link:

```
jQuery("a.next").click(function(e) {
    return ngg_ajax_navigation(e, this);
});
```

I'd like to have this happen automatically every 3 seconds in addition to when the user clicks the link. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Broader code:

```
function ngg_ajax_browser_navigation(e, obj) {


// try to find gallery number
if ("ngg-prev-" == jQuery(obj).attr("id").substr(0, 9) || "ngg-next-" == jQuery(obj).attr("id").substr(0, 9)) {

    // extract the image-id
    var imageNumber = jQuery(obj).attr("id").substr(9);

    // find the image-browser-container
    var currentNode = obj;
    while (null != currentNode.parentNode && !jQuery.nodeName(currentNode.parentNode, "body") && !jQuery(currentNode.parentNode).hasClass("ngg-imagebrowser")) {
        currentNode = currentNode.parentNode;
    }

    if (jQuery(currentNode.parentNode).hasClass("ngg-imagebrowser")) {
        var gallery = jQuery(currentNode.parentNode);

        // let's extract the post id & gallery id
        var payload = gallery.attr("id").substring(17);
        var separatorPosition = parseInt(payload.indexOf("-"));

        var galleryId = payload.substr(0, separatorPosition);
        var postId = payload.substr(separatorPosition + 1);

        if ( (galleryId.length == 0) || (postId.length == 0) ) {
            return true;
        }

        ngg_show_loading(e);

        // get content
        jQuery.get(ngg_ajax.callback, {p: postId, galleryid: galleryId, pid: imageNumber, type: "browser"}, function (data, textStatus) {
            // delete old content
            gallery.children().remove();

            // add new content
            gallery.replaceWith(data);

            // add ajax-navigation, again
            jQuery("document").ready(function(){
                // remove old listeners to avoid double-clicks
                jQuery("a.ngg-browser-next").unbind("click");
                jQuery("a.ngg-browser-prev").unbind("click");

                // add shutter-listeners again
                shutterReloaded.init('sh');

                // register ajax browser-navigation listeners
                jQuery("a.ngg-browser-next").click(function(e) {
                    return ngg_ajax_browser_navigation(e, this);
                });
                jQuery("a.ngg-browser-prev").click(function(e) {
                    return ngg_ajax_browser_navigation(e, this);
                });

                setInterval(function(){
                    jQuery("a.ngg-browser-next").click();
                }, 3000);

                ngg_remove_loading();
            });
        });

        // deactivate HTML link
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery("a.next").click(function(e) {
    return ngg_ajax_navigation(e, this);
});

setInterval(function(){
    jQuery("a.next").click();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Here's the broader code in case I'm missing something:

Comment: Of course it helps if I put the setInterval in jQuery("document").ready(function(). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put the code to advance the slideshow in a named function (actually, you've mostly done that), and call the function via either `setTimeout` (which you'd have to reschedule each time) or `setInterval` (which recurs automatically). E.g.:

```
(function(element) {
    var timer = 0,                   // Timer handle, 0 = not running
        $element = jQuery("a.next"), // jQuery wrapper on element
        element = $element[0];       // Raw element

    // The click handler
    $element.click(function(e) {
        startTimer();
        return ngg_ajax_navigation(e, element);
    });

    // Timer
    startTimer();
    function startTimer() {
        if (timer) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = 0;
        }
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            ngg_ajax_navigation(null, element);
        }, 3000);
    }
})();
```

In the above, I've made it so that an explicit click resets the timer. If you want to offer a way to stop the slideshow, just have something that does `clearInterval(timer); timer = 0;`. Also note that I wrapped everything in a function to avoid creating globals, and only looked up the element once.

The above assumes there's only one `a.next` element. It will need refactoring if there's more than one.